# Removing duplicate results from the loop output in Python

Tags: python

My data from a loop generates a series of strings which are sentences retrieved from a database. However, my data structure in the database needs to have duplicates but I want to omit the duplicates in the output. Assuming my loop and results is as follow:

```
for text in document:
   print(text)
```

Output:

```
He goes to school.
He works here.
we are friends.
He goes to school.
they are leaving us alone.
..........
```

How can I set up a condition so that the program reads all the output generated and if find duplicate results (eg. He goes to school) it will only show one record of to me instead of multiple similar records?

Comment: You need to define your condition for duplicate, and it might not be the ideal place to perform the test. For instance, in SQL you can use "select distinct" to avoid duplicates. The two strings you said are duplicates in this case differ in the case of the first letter.

Comment: See **`unique_everseen`** in [**`itertools`** recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: Sorry, it was capital letter so they are identical. But the issue is that my data structure is very complicated, it is basically a NoSQL DB which retrieve this from different resources so duplication is and needs to be part of the structure for that field. I need a python filter for the display output only so that to show them neatly rather than applying it from the DB level.

Comment: Does order matter?

Answer (score 3):

```
already_printed = set()
for text in document:
   if text not in already_printed:
       print(text)
       already_printed.add(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set`. Like:

```
values = set(document)
for text in values:
   print(text)
```

Or can use `list`:

```
temp_list = []
for text in document:
   if text not in temp_list:
       temp_list.append(text)
       print(text)
```

Or you can use `dict`:

```
temp_dict={}
for text in document:
   if text not in temp_dict.keys():
       temp_dict[text]=1
       print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split document by '\n' or read by rows to `arr = []`. I.e. in `for` loop store `arr += row.lowercase()`.

`arr = list(set(arr))` will remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If the case does not matter, you can take set of the list.

```
for text in set(i.lower() for i in document):
    print (text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use built in option SET of python to remove duplicates

```
documents = ["He goes to school", "He works here. we are friends", "He goes to school", "they are leaving us alone"]

list(set(document))
```

Comment: Is order important?

Comment: Why do we need to convert the `set` into `list`?

Comment: @TaohidulIslam for computation :-)